# python.clang AST parsing: getting c++ template argument of field declaration

Tags: python, c++, templates, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using the abstract syntax tree that clang provides through the python interface, trying to parse a simple structure containing a std::vector:

```
#include <vector>

struct outer_t
{
    std::vector<int> vec_of_ints;
};
```

I would like to get the template argument of the vector, but I cannot find a reference to it in the respective node of the AST. The get_num_template_arguments() member function returns -1. I therefore think that the get_template_* functions cannot be used.
I tried the following:

```
import sys
import clang.cindex
clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file("/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libclang.so.1")

class Walker:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def walk(self, node):
        node_in_file =  bool(node.location.file and node.location.file.name == self.filename)
        if node_in_file:
            print(f"node.spelling = {node.spelling:14}, node.kind = {node.kind}")
            if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.TEMPLATE_REF:
                print(f"node.get_num_template_arguments = {node.get_num_template_arguments()}")
        for child in node.get_children():
            self.walk(child)

filename = sys.argv[1]
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
translation_unit = index.parse(filename)

root = translation_unit.cursor        
walker = Walker(filename)
walker.walk(root)
```

This produces the following result:

```
node.spelling = vec_of_ints   , node.kind = CursorKind.FIELD_DECL
node.spelling = std           , node.kind = CursorKind.NAMESPACE_REF
node.spelling = vector        , node.kind = CursorKind.TEMPLATE_REF
node.get_num_template_arguments = -1
```

Is there another way to get the template argument or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

The `TEMPLATE_REF` cursor kind doesn't seem to have any information about its arguments, at least for this example; I don't know why.  But `FIELD_DECL` has a `type` that can have template arguments.  Here is a minimally modified version of your code that prints the number of template arguments for the `vec_of_ints` field in your example code:

```
import sys
import clang.cindex
clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file("/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libclang.so.1")

class Walker:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def walk(self, node):
        node_in_file =  bool(node.location.file and node.location.file.name == self.filename)
        if node_in_file:
            print(f"node.spelling = {node.spelling:14}, node.kind = {node.kind}")
            # -------- BEGIN modified section --------
            type = node.type
            if type is not None:
                ntargs = type.get_num_template_arguments()
                if ntargs > 0:
                    print(f"  type.spelling = {type.spelling}")
                    print(f"  type.get_num_template_arguments = {ntargs}")
            # -------- END modified section --------
        for child in node.get_children():
            self.walk(child)

filename = sys.argv[1]
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
translation_unit = index.parse(filename)

root = translation_unit.cursor
walker = Walker(filename)
walker.walk(root)
```

When run on your example input file, I get:

```
node.spelling = outer_t       , node.kind = CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL
node.spelling = vec_of_ints   , node.kind = CursorKind.FIELD_DECL
  type.spelling = std::vector<int>
  type.get_num_template_arguments = 1
node.spelling = std           , node.kind = CursorKind.NAMESPACE_REF
node.spelling = vector        , node.kind = CursorKind.TEMPLATE_REF
```

I don't claim this will handle all cases of templates appearing in code.  I discovered the above through a combination of trial and error and reading the [`clang/cindex.py`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py) library module source file.  But it hopefully serves as a useful starting point.

In any case, one important thing to understand about the Clang AST (and pretty much all C/C++ ASTs) is that types are not nodes in the main syntax tree.  Rather, types are semantic *interpretations* of some nodes in that tree, and thus sort of sit to the side.  That's why they don't appear as arguments to `walk`.